# Android: Pass data into a Custom View Class?

Tags: android

I'm creating my first game in Android. And in part of the game, I'm drawing a path and I want the path to start at the center of a `RelativeLayout`. I'm successfully getting the center coordinates, but now I need to pass those coordinates (`int xCenterInt, yCenterInt;`) to my custom View, and that's what I can't figure out. I can't get Intents to work, unless I'm doing Intents incorrectly. So how can I pass my int values into my Custom View Class? Here's the method I'm using in my Main Activity to get the center coordinates:

```
public void getBoardNumbers() {
    gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(NumbersoGLL);
}


OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        xScrInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth();
        yScrInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight();

        xScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        yScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        xCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScr2Int;
        yCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScr2Int;

        //---- How do I get xCenterInt, yCenterInt to my DrawPath Class?

    }
};
```

Here's my Custom View Class where the coordinates need to be plugged in:

```
public class DrawPath extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
int xC_Int, yC_Int;

//--- The coordinates Integers need to go here:
Pt[] thePath = { new Pt(xC_Int, yC_Int),
        new Pt(200, 200),
        new Pt(200, 500),
        new Pt(400, 500) };

public DrawPath(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    path.moveTo(thePath[0].x, thePath[0].y);
    for (int i = 1; i < thePath.length; i++) {
        path.lineTo(thePath[i].x, thePath[i].y);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}// --- END onDraw

class Pt {
    float x, y;

    Pt(float _x, float _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}//--- END PT
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I changed some variable names (I was getting bored with the other names), and the `getBoardNumbers()` method got modified and now I'm dynamically creating the game board layout in the method as well. So here's the method and the new `DrawPath` class, now called `PathEM`:

```
    // -- Get GameBoard info using oGLL
public void getGameBoard() {
    LayInf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE = LayInf.inflate(R.layout.game1_info, null);
    gBoardInfo_LP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gBoardInfo_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,
            RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setId(2);
    gBoardInfo_VUE.setLayoutParams(gBoardInfo_LP);
    gameTime_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE
            .findViewById(R.id.game1_timeValue2_TV);
    gameScore_TV = (TextView) gBoardInfo_VUE
            .findViewById(R.id.game1_scoreValue2_TV);
    root_RL.addView(gBoardInfo_VUE);

    gBoard_RL = new RelativeLayout(this);
    gBoard_LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    gBoard_LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, gBoardInfo_VUE.getId());
    gBoard_LP.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gBoard_RL.setLayoutParams(gBoard_LP);
    gBoard_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(NumbersoGLL);

    //--- add stuff here
    root_RL.addView(gBoard_RL);

    root_FrameL = new FrameLayout(this);
    root_FrameL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    root_FrameL.addView(root_RL);
    setContentView(root_FrameL);
}


// -- oGLL
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        xScrInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth();
        yScrInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight();

        xRLWInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        yRLHInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        xTint = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xRLWInt;
        yTint = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yRLHInt;

        path_em = new PathEM(getApplicationContext(), xTint, yTint);
        gBoard_RL.addView(path_em);
    }
};// --- END oGLL
    // -- END Get GameBoard info using oGLL


//--- PathEM Class
public class PathEM extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();

    public PathEM(Context context, int xTint, int yTint){
        super(context);
    }

    Pt[] thePath = { new Pt(xTint, yTint),
            new Pt(200, 200),
            new Pt(200, 500),
            new Pt(400, 500)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        path.moveTo(thePath[0].x, thePath[0].y);
        for (int i = 1; i < thePath.length; i++) {
            path.lineTo(thePath[i].x, thePath[i].y);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }// --- END onDraw

    class Pt {
        float x, y;

        Pt(float _x, float _y) {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
    }// --- END PT
}//--- END PathEM Class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a **setter - getter** for `xCenterInt` and `yCenterInt` in your `DrawPath` class, example :

```
public class DrawPath extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
int xC_Int, yC_Int;
int xCenterInt, yCenterInt; //create new variables

//your other codes

public void setxCenterInt(int setxCenterInt) {
   this.setxCenterInt = setxCenterInt;
}

public int getxCenterInt() {
   return setxCenterInt;
}

//do the same for yCenterInt
```

After that, use the **setter-getter** we created earlier :

```
OnGlobalLayoutListener NumbersoGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        xScrInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth();
        yScrInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight();

        xScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getWidth() / 2;
        yScr2Int = gBoard_RL.getHeight() / 2;
        xCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScr2Int;
        yCenterInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScr2Int;

        //use your DrawPath instance
        myDrawPathInstance.setxCenterInt(xCenterInt);
        //do the same for yCenterInt
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting a `NullPointerException();` at `myDrawPathInstance.setxCenterInt(xCenterInt);` in the method, which means that the setter-getter isn't set up right. I'm looking into it. I like your solution, though, I just gotta make it work for me.

Comment: @kirktoon1882 Please make sure "myDrawPathInstance" is already initialized. If it still not working, please update your question with your current code